# Local Storage in Ionic 2 not able access the data outside then() method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, ionic2

I'm learning Ionic 2. I've stored some data in **ionic local storage** inside a **SomeComponent** and retriving the same in **UserService** to call backend but `storage.get()` method returns **Promise** so i can't get data out of it as i learnt about promises. Can anybody assist me better way to get this job done? Thanks if any.

here is my code.

```
export class SomeComponent {

 user: User;
 usename: string;
 password: string;

   constructor(
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public navController: NavController, 
    public loginService: LoginSevice,
    public storage: Storage) {

   }

    login() {
        this.loginService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe( response => {
          this.user = response;
          this.storage.set('userId', this.user.userId);
          this.storage.set( 'authcode', this.user.authCode);
        });
      }
}
```

And the service is

```
    export class UserService {

      userId: string;
      constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage){}

      fetchUserInfo(): Observable<User> { 

          this.storage.get('userId').then((val) => {
            console.log(val); // available only inside then() method
            this.userId = val; 
          });

          let user = btoa(this.userId); // userId is undefined
          return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/user/${user}/details`, {headers: 
               this.headers})
             .map(res =>res.json());
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @echonax Hi Sir, Is there any other way to store and retrieve data from local storage in ionic.

Comment: I'm not really experienced with ionic. But the official documentation suggest using that so I think that'd be the best.

Comment: @echonax thanks for the immediate reply. can you explain me how to return a promise from then() function that resolve to a string value.

Comment: You should read the link :-)

Comment: @echonax Ok  thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this scenario would be like this:

```
export class UserService {

    userId: string;
    constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage){}

    fetchUserInfo(): Observable<User> { 

        return Observable
            .fromPromise(this.storage.get('userId'))
            .flatMap(userId => 
                this.userId = val;

                let user = btoa(this.userId);
                return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/user/${user}/details`, {headers: this.headers})
                           .map(res =>res.json());
    }
}
```

This way, we're first creating an observable with the promise that will return the value (`userId`) from the storage, and then using that `userId` we're making the http request (that will return the `Observable<User>`). You can find more information about the `flatmap` operator [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html).

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `mergeMAp` this also works perfectly. I don't know the difference of using both `flatMap` and `mergMap` but it works.

```
export class UserService {
    userId: string;
    constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage){}
    fetchUserInfo(): Observable<User> { 
    return Observable
          .fromPromise(this.storage.get('userId')).mergeMap(userId => 
              this.userId = val;
              let user = btoa(this.userId);
              return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/user/${user}/details`, {headers: this.headers})
                               .map(res =>res.json());
    }
}
```